# Is my 15-month old drinking too much fluids?

Tags: toddler, health, food, drinking

My 15-month old is Mr. Thirst. He is weened (about 2 months now), but he has ravenous thirst and drinks about 50-60 ounces (ca. 1,6 liters) a day of fluids. We give him soy milk (he might be lactose-intolerant, we're not sure) and water, and occasionally watered-down juice. It seems to be way, way more than I first child needed. And most frustratingly, he demands fluids throughout the night.

Is this normal?

Comment: That sounds very thirsty. If you're also looking for other fluids for the sake of variety or to direct him away from other choices, consider watered-down fruit teas as well (but no black tea), they mostly taste pleasant and contain no sugars, coffeine, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is definitely something you should bring to the pediatrician's attention.  It may be normal, but it can also be a sign of diabetes.  Also, I caution against giving a child more than a couple cups of soy milk even if they are lactose-intolerant.  The evidence is inconclusive but [soy phytoestrogens may promote certain types of cancer](http://envirocancer.cornell.edu/factsheet/diet/fs1.phyto.cfm).  Soy milk also does not have as much fat as whole milk and dietary fat is crucial for brain development.  Regardless, 50-60 oz. is a lot of fluid and worth getting a professional opinion on.

Comment: please add references when you make a claim like *soy phytoestrogens may promote certain types of cancer* in order for your statement to be verifiable and credible.

Answer (score 7):

Usually the child knows best. As long as he is filling his diapers regularly and not showing any signs of sickness he should be fine. However in this situation I would take the little one to visit a doctor to check for any known diseases with this as a symptom.

Maybe he has some problem eating (due to teething etc) and rather drinks a lot then eat a lot. Maybe it is summer now and his body simply needs more fluids then you're previous child or he is growing faster/slower different.